# How to upload an array of image on godaddy server?

Tags: php, image, upload, localhost

I write code because I needed to upload multiple images into my website to show some details. I'm setting up my website to godaddy server and some error occurs but this one of uploading multiple images is not working. It worked on localhost. This is the errors I got:

> [28-Mar-2019 03:18:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): The
>   second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in
>   /home/v1pyvnw05stp/public_html/**.php on line 123 [28-Mar-2019
>   03:18:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move;

When I look in to the folders I notice there are at least two image in a place they shouldn't but as a test/x-generic files

```
  $photocount = count($_FILES['photo']['name']);
  if ($photocount > 0) {
for($i = 0; $i<$photocount;$i++){
  $name = $_FILES['photo']['name'][$i];
  $nameArray = explode('.',$name);
  $filename=$nameArray[0];
  $fileExt = $nameArray[1];
  $mime = explode('/',$_FILES['photo']['type'][$i]);
  $mimeType = $mime[0];
  $mimeExt = $mime[1];
  $tmpLoc[] = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$i];
  $fileSize = $_FILES['photo']['size'][$i];
  $uploadName = md5(microtime().$i).'.'.$fileExt;
  $uploadPath = '/home/v1pyvnw05stp/public_html/images/Articulos/'.$uploadName;
  if($i != 0){
    $dbpath .= ',';
  }
  $dbpath = '/images/Articulos/'.$uploadName;


  if($photocount > 0){
      for($i = 0;$i<$photocount;$i++){
    move_uploaded_file($tmpLoc[$i],$uploadPath[$i]); THIS IS THE ERROR LINE AND IF I ERASE $I OF $UPLOADPAH THE SISTEM WORK BUT JUST WITH ONE IMAGE.
  }
}
```

I ALREADY CHANGE PERMISSIONS

Answer (score 0):

You are getting errors you are passing a wrong argument in the `move_uploaded_file()` method. The 2nd arg `$uploadPath[$i]` is not an array but a string defined in your code. Make the following changes ,

```
$photocount = count($_FILES['photo']['name']);
  if ($photocount > 0) {
for($i = 0; $i<$photocount;$i++){
  $name = $_FILES['photo']['name'][$i];
  $nameArray = explode('.',$name);
  $filename=$nameArray[0];
  $fileExt = $nameArray[1];
  $mime = explode('/',$_FILES['photo']['type'][$i]);
  $mimeType = $mime[0];
  $mimeExt = $mime[1];
  $tmpLoc[] = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$i];
  $fileSize = $_FILES['photo']['size'][$i];
  $uploadName = md5(microtime().$i).'.'.$fileExt;
  $uploadPath = '/home/v1pyvnw05stp/public_html/images/Articulos/'.$uploadName;
  if($i != 0){
    $dbpath .= ',';
  }
  $dbpath = '/images/Articulos/'.$uploadName;


  if($photocount > 0){
      for($i = 0;$i<$photocount;$i++){
    move_uploaded_file($tmpLoc[$i],$uploadPath);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is what I did but when I upload multiple images it just upload the lastest and the others are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute path of your server directory.

Replace $uploadPath = '/home/v1pyvnw05stp/public_html/images/Articulos/'.$uploadName;
with  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'images/Articulos/'.$uploadName;

Replace `move_uploaded_file($tmpLoc[$i],$uploadPath[$i]);`
with

move_uploaded_file($tmpLoc[$i],$uploadPath);

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out why I was getting that error and is because I should add [] to $uploadpath. Now I'm not getting errors but I can't add more than one $dbpath to the database. Some ideas why?

```
$uploadPath**[]** = '/home/v1pyvnw05stp/public_html/images/Articulos/'.$uploadName;
  if($photocount > 0){
  for($i = 0;$i<$photocount;$i++){
move_uploaded_file($tmpLoc[$i],$uploadPath[$i]);
```

}